# Restore an Oracle Database from dpump File

Tags: database, oracle

I installed Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 7. I chose an installation software only without creating any Database, because my goal is creating databases by restoring from dpump files.
When I use impdp with sysdba user to restore my database, I get the following errors :

```
> UDI-01034: operation generated ORACLE error 1034 ORA-01034: ORACLE not
> available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Linux-x86_64
> Error: 2: No such file or directory Additional information: 3640
> Additional information: 291541407 UDI-00003: all allowable logon
> attempts failed
```

Do I have to create a least one database during the installation software or with dbca tool to be able to import other databases form dpump files ?

Comment: "*Do I have to create a least one database during the installation software*" - yes without a database instance you can't import anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can't import into a non-existent database. You need to create one with DBCA, then you can use your impdp to put it back in. Keep in mind that if you're using pluggables, you'll need to connect to a service that is assigned to that pluggable, or you'll have issues.

-Jim